# fancybox scroll is not displayed on the iPad, but displayed in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, ipad, fancybox

I have [a page where the scrollbar in the fancybox is not displayed from iPad but is displayed from Google Chrome from Desktop](http://jsfiddle.net/wqm0x21n/1/) The URL is http://jsfiddle.net/wqm0x21n/1/ You can scroll the fancybox content, but there is no vertical scroll bar when visit from iPad.

Any ideas how to make it work?
Any solutions found as SO such as applying:

```
#fancybox-inner{
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

didn't help.

And here is jsfiddle code, if needed:

JS:

```
$(".fancyTrigger").fancybox({
    fitToView: false,
    autoSize: false,
    afterLoad: function () {
        this.width = 200;
        this.height = 200;
    }
});
$(".fancyTrigger").trigger('click');
```

CSS:

```
#TheFancybox {
    display: none;
}

#fancybox-inner{
    overflow:scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm, I’ve taken a closer look at your code and made the following adjustments for you:

1. Although referenced in you css, you were missing your #fancybox-inner div container element in your html. See this updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nxn46e3t/
2. Have modified your CSS so parent DIV is reference for scrolling, we also need to tell it how big to be (hence the width and height attributes set to 100%)

> ```
>   body {
>        background-color: #eef;     
>     }
>     #TheFancybox {
>      overflow:auto;
>      -webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;
>      width: 100%;
>      height: 100%;  
>     }
>
>     #fancybox-inner{
>
>     }
> ```

I’ve tested on IOS and your scrollbar now appears when scrolling:
[image: test]

Complete working jsfiddle example can be found here (as above) http://jsfiddle.net/nxn46e3t/

Let me know how that works for you.

Good luck!